# Aurelia send config/parameters on initialisation aurelia-app

Tags: aurelia

Is there any way to send let's say config parameters when initializing an Aurelia app?

```
<div aurelia-app="my-app/main"></div>
```

This is what I do to start my aurelia app and then

```
<script>
  System.import('aurelia-bootstrapper');
</script>
```

I'd like to do something like:

```
<div aurelia-app="my-app/main" param1="something" param2="false"></div>
```

Right now I'm setting them as `data-param1` attributes and then getting the values in the controller like `Element.dataset.param1`

Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: I think what you got there is perfect for what it is. You can optionally embed some JSON in the page but I don't see anything wrong with your approach.

Comment: what I have is not bad, but I was looking for something better. with the data- attribute I can only send "text", sure I can send a stringify object and then parse it on my JS, but I wanted something better. thanks!

Comment: If it's content embeded from your server, then there is noway else. otherwise, you can leverage the async nature of bootstrapping configure function to fetch data dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it that I think it works pretty well. As I'm using SystemJS I found out I can do something like this when initialising my Aurelia app:

```
System.set('my-config', System.newModule({
  Params: {
    param1: true,
    param2: 'something',
    param3: [
      {
        name: 'whatever',
      },
    ]
  }
}));

System.import('aurelia-bootstrapper');
```

And then, the `Params` module is available in the whole app, so I can import it and use it:

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {Params} from 'my-config';

@inject(Params)
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(params) {
    //params.param1 etc...
  }
}
```

Pretty handy in my opinion. I hope it helps!